# Fiber Channel (8 Gb) or iSCSI 10 Gb

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, storage-area-network, iscsi

I'd like to know your opinion about this based on your experience working with iSCI and Fiber Channel, I think i'm gonna keep with iSCSI 10Gb, but want to know what you guys think about this:

I have available 2 storage servers, one of them have an 8 Gb Fiber Channel interface, the other one have 10 GB ethernet connection for iSCSI. Right now I'm storing the Virtual machines on the local disk on each servers (5 physical servers). I want use one of this to store my VMs (using vmware esxi), wich one do you think is more convenient? 8 GB Fiber Channel or 10 Gb ISCSI? I already have the 10 GB switches and some of our server have 10 GB ethernet nic, so the iSCSI option is convenient in the economic side, but what about performance? should I buy the Fiber Channel switch and hba cards or use 10 Gb iSCSI?

Regards.

Comment: I believe this post is too opinion based- there's no answer other than "either, and this is my opinion".

Comment: Yep, you're right, I just wanna hear opinions about this. I've edited the question to clear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iSCSI will be fine here, especially since you already have so much of the infrastructure for it. While fiber would be less susceptible to interference, a 2Gb/s difference is enough to make up for that in typical situations. iSCSI is capable of being routed (since it uses IP), if that interests you at all. Also, the fiber HBAs and cable are consistently more expensive. Comparable switches are about the same cost for 10Gb copper as for 8Gb fiber. iSCSI is also the choice for many converged networks and other forms of SDS / SDN.

FC, on the other hand, has very little protocol overhead. It also provides a truly serialized interface and is almost completely lossless. The latency is stunningly low, and it outperforms iSCSI under heavy pressure consistently. If you're using this for a very busy storage network that would benefit from very low overhead and latency, then FC would be a very good choice. It's more expensive, but you may find down the line that it's worth it as your needs grow.

Don't be too drawn in by theoretical bandwidth numbers. 10Gb/s may seem like a lot more than 8Gb/s, but overhead plays a huge role in iSCSI communication. After all of this is considered, the two will perform roughly identically (IF you have configured your network and hosts appropriately), with iSCSI pulling ahead in throughput and FC showing lower latency and lossiness. iSCSI has more software defined tools available for it, due to its more flexible nature. SDS tools, while they exist for FC, are currently quite limited in comparison.

Comment: Good answer. Also, looking at current storage trends, iSCSI seems to be the more preferable direction to invest into. More and more software-defined storage providers are developing their appliances with iSCSI support in the first place.

Comment: IMO  the *advantage* of iSCSI is that it shares infrastructure with "normal" Ethernet networking, while the *disadvantage* of iSCSI is that is shares infrastructure with "normal" Ethernet networking.  If your requirements are such that you *need* a dedicated storage-only network, FC can make sense.  I'd also think it'd be hard for someone unfamiliar with the technologies to even come up with a way to test the performance difference between 8gb FC and 10 gb iSCSI.  And both technologies can be misconfigured such that performance is terrible...